# Sum of group by using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having three tables financial_year, house_details, consumer_details. I need to get the sum of each tax group by year and subincome.  My table and query is in this link: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0313/14)

Getting Result:

```
Name  house_number  address  subincome   financial_year  gtax  htax  LTAX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bala  22            Mumbai   Garbage tax 2015-2016       200   NULL  NULL
Bala  22            Mumbai   Garbage tax 2016-2017       250   NULL  NULL
Bala  22            Mumbai   House tax   2015-2016       NULL  0     NULL
Bala  22            Mumbai   House tax   2016-2017       NULL  145   NULL
Bala  22            Mumbai   Light tax   2015-2016       NULL  NULL  510
Bala  22            Mumbai   Light tax   2016-2017       NULL  NULL  200
```

Expecting Result:

```
Name    house_number    address    gtax    htax    LTAX
--------------------------------------------------------
Bala    22              Mumbai     450     145     710
```

Comment: Paste your result as text, not image. Some people can't see images.

Comment: Link is to image not sqlfiddle.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes i updated please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation note this solution only works if there is an entry for each subincome(tax type)in house details for each financial year.

```
SELECT c.consumer_name as Name, c.house_number, c.address,
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN f.garbage_tax else 0 end) - 
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as gtax, 
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN f.house_tax else 0 end) -
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as htax, 
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN f.light_tax else 0 end) - 
sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as LTAX 
from house_details h 
INNER JOIN financial_year f ON h.financial_year = f.year AND h.house_id = f.house_number 
INNER JOIN consumer_details c ON h.house_id = c.house_number AND h.financial_year != '2017-2018' 
group by c.consumer_name , c.house_number, c.address
```

result

```
+------+--------------+---------+------+------+------+
| Name | house_number | address | gtax | htax | LTAX |
+------+--------------+---------+------+------+------+
| Bala | 22           | Mumbai  |  450 |  145 |  710 |
+------+--------------+---------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

If it is not guaranteed that there will be an entry for every subincome in every financial year then the the solution has to be driven from the tax due table (financial year) which in my view is badly designed ,inflexible and forces a sub optimal solution

```
select c.consumer_name as Name, s.house_number, c.address,
        sum(case when subincome = 'garbage tax' then taxdue else 0 end) - sum(case when subincome = 'garbage tax' then taxpaid else 0 end) as gtax,
        sum(case when subincome = 'house tax' then taxdue else 0 end) - sum(case when subincome = 'house tax' then taxpaid else 0 end) as htax,
        sum(case when subincome = 'light tax' then taxdue else 0 end) - sum(case when subincome = 'light tax' then taxpaid else 0 end) as ltax
from 
(
SELECT  F.`house_number`, F.`year`, F.`house_tax` taxdue, F.`createdAt`, F.`updatedAt`,ifnull(h.subincome,'house_tax') subincome,ifnull(H.RUPEES,0) taxpaid
FROM FINANCIAL_YEARS F
LEFT  JOIN house_details H ON H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'house tax' and f.year = h.financial_year
#where f.house_number = 22
union all
SELECT F.`house_number`, F.`year`, F.`light_tax`,  F.`createdAt`, F.`updatedAt`,ifnull(h.subincome,'light tax'),ifnull(H.RUPEES,0) 
FROM FINANCIAL_YEARS F
LEFT  JOIN house_details H ON H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'light tax' and f.year = h.financial_year
#where f.house_number = 2
union all
SELECT F.`house_number`, F.`year`, F.`garbage_tax`, F.`createdAt`, F.`updatedAt`,ifnull(h.subincome,'garbage tax'),ifnull(H.RUPEES,0) 
FROM FINANCIAL_YEARS F
LEFT  JOIN house_details H ON H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'garbage tax' and f.year = h.financial_year
#where f.house_number = 2
) s
join consumer_details c on s.house_number = c.house_number
where s.year <> '2017-2018'
group by c.consumer_name , s.house_number, c.address
```

Comment: Please check updated answer. BTW you may want to change some of your table and column names to make them more meaningful.

Comment: can you please explain what taxdue field used for.

Comment: In a union(or union all) statement the number of fields supplied must be the same, taxdue is an alias for the 3 taxes you have , i could have used almost any string instead of taxdue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will give exact result which you want, I just create a drive table and then sum

```
SELECT name
     , house_number
     , address
     , SUM(gtax) as gtax
     , SUM(htax) as htax
     , SUM(LTAX) LTAX
FROM (SELECT c.consumer_name as Name
           , c.house_number
           , c.address,h.subincome
           , h.financial_year
           , CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN f.garbage_tax - sum(h.rupees)END as gtax
           , CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN f.house_tax - sum(h.rupees) END as htax
           , CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN f.light_tax - sum(h.rupees) END as LTAX
      FROM house_details h
          INNER JOIN financial_year f ON h.financial_year = f.year AND h.house_id = f.house_number
          INNER JOIN consumer_details c ON h.house_id = c.house_number AND h.financial_year != '2017-2018'
      GROUP BY h.subincome, h.financial_year) as main
GROUP BY house_number
```

then result is :
[image: Screenshot of result]